# How to dll import and export HINSTANCE from a .dll in c++?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, dllimport, dllexport

I am trying to get the `HINSTANCE` of a `.dll`, but I get this error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) struct HINSTANCE__ * m_instance" (__imp_?m_instance@@3PEAUHINSTANCE__@@EA) referenced in function...

This is the code of the `.dll`:

```
#include <Windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) HINSTANCE m_instance;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        m_instance = (HINSTANCE)hModule;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

This is the code of the application:

```
__declspec(dllimport) HINSTANCE m_instance;

// use it for whatev
```

In summary, I need a way to get the `HINSTANCE` from my `.dll` into my `.exe`.

Comment: How do you link that DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In summary, I need a way to get the `HINSTANCE` from my `.dll` into my `.exe`.

But, why??? Once the `.exe` has loaded the `.dll` into its memory, the `.exe` *already* has access to the `.dll`'s `HINSTANCE`, from the return value of either `LoadLibrary/Ex()` or `GetModuleHandle()`. So, there is *never* a need to have a `.dll` export its own `HINSTANCE`.

Comment: maybe dll static linked to exe, in this case we not have base of dll,but unclear for what this can be need. however always posible get this by using any exported function address from dll ( `GetModuleHandleExW(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS|GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, (PCWSTR)SomeFuncFromDll, &hmod);`) . formally need look actually exported name from dll. possible this is *c* compiled as result not in form `__imp_?m_instance@@3PEAUHINSTANCE__@@EA`

Comment: @RbMm "*maybe dll static linked to exe, in this case we not have base of dll*" - Yes, you can still get the DLL's `HINSTANCE` in that scenario, using `GetModuleHandle("filename.dll")`.

Comment: For that to work the DLL name needs to be known in code. This produces a hidden dependency between the code and the build system. A dependency that cannot be verified at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The application is failing to link against the DLL's import library. By default, MSVC's linker generates an import library (LIB) when producing a DLL, that has the same base name as the DLL.

To allow the linker to resolve the symbol `m_instance` the application needs the DLL's import library as a [linker input file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/link-input-files). See [.Lib Files as Linker Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dot-lib-files-as-linker-input) to learn how to add linker input files in Visual Studio.

Though not strictly required, it's usually a good idea to export symbols using C linkage. While C++ linkage is largely unspecified and very toolchain-specific, C name decoration is de-facto standardized. The changes required are tiny (though, again, not required):

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) HINSTANCE m_instance;
```

and

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) HINSTANCE m_instance;
```